# Correcting timezones using momentjs

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am currently trying to adjust a timezone from an API that is sending a 'wrongish' time.

example:

```
serverTimestamp = '2020-04-23T15:00:00.000+0000'
serverTimezone = 'America/New_York'
```

The actual serverTimezone is 'America/Los_Angeles'

the server timestamp is 8 am pacific time but the timezone is saying it is New York time.
Using momentJs, how would I convert `serverTimestamp` to the correct time (8 am New York time) as a UTC time?

Answer (score 0):

We can adjust the timezone according to our requirements with the use of `moment.js`

> Use `moment.tz.setDefault("GMT");` for changing the timezone of defult date picker

```
    $('#startdatetimepicker').datetimepicker({
        defaultDate: new Date()
    });

    $('#enddatetimepicker').datetimepicker();
```

Answer (score 0):

The timestamp is actually GMT/UTC (+0000). EST and PST fluctuate by an hour, depending on whether the US is in daylight savings. Your NY time would be '2020-04-23T11:00:00.000-0400' and your LA time would be '2020-04-23T08:00:00.000-0700'.

These are all the same time, as far as ISO timestamps are concerned. A user's computer (or a server) will automatically convert it to their local timezone.

If you want to use moment to convert the actual timestamp string to PST, you can use the [moment-timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/) extension.

Comment: thanks for that explanation Blake! in fact i am using moment-timezone and have something like this `moment(serverTime).tz('America/New_York').utc().format()` which gives me `2020-04-23T15:00:00Z` this is still not 8am New York Time...

Comment: Right. It's 3pm London time, 11am NY time and 8am LA time. From what I'm seeing it's correct. What do you get with ```moment(serverTime).tz('America/New_York').format(moment.ISO_8601)```?